# Java Map Adding Key Values

Tags: java, dictionary

**Method :**

```
public void itemAmountCollection() {
    Map<String, List<Integer>> orderItemDetails = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<Integer>>();
            ArrayList<Integer> itemsAmount = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            WebElement orderItemTable = driver.findElement(By
                    .xpath("//*[@id='tblInfo']/tbody"));
            List<WebElement> noOfItems = orderItemTable.findElements(By
                    .tagName("tr"));
            for (int i = 1; i <= noOfItems.size(); i++) {
                String itemAmount = driver.findElement(
                        By.xpath("//*[@id='tblInfo']/tbody/tr[" + i
                                + "]/td[8]")).getText();
                itemsAmount.add(Integer.parseInt(itemAmount));
                orderItemDetails.put("amount", itemsAmount);
            }
        }
```

with above method we collected all the item amount with Map Collections and Output for the above **`method is (345,7905,345)`**
how can we add all the values in an particular Key (amount)

**Expected Output :**

```
8595 (i.e 345+7905+345)
```

Comment: If you do `List<Integer> valuesForItem = map.get(key)`, then do you know how to do the rest?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get what you mean, but I'm amusing that you're trying to add all values in a `List`. To do this:

```
int result = 0;
for(int i : itemsAmount)
{
    result+=1;
}
System.out.println(result);//This should print 8595.
```

Answer (score 0):

In general `Map<Key,List<Value>>` structures end up needing code that looks as follows:

```
public addValue(Key key, Value value) {
    if (!map.containsKey(key)) {
        map.put(key, new ArrayList<>());
    }
    map.get(key).add(value);
}
```

In your case you should replace `orderItemDetails.put` with similar code.

Alternatively you could use a true Multimap from a third party library such as guava.

Summing the values would simply be:

```
map.get(key).stream().sum();
```

Assuming that the values are List which makes the stream an IntStream.